# Vuetify v-dialog would not open - :value property does not work

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuex

I just tried to create a separate form using Vue and vuetify's v-dialog. Unfortunately, once taken into separate component the thing stopped working without any error.

Here's the code to my component:

```
<template>
    <v-dialog :value="dialogOpen" persistent>
        <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
            <v-btn color="primary" v-bind="props">Add new</v-btn>
        </template>
        <v-card>
            <v-card-title>
                <span class="text-h5">Subscriber</span>
            </v-card-title>
            <v-card-text>
                <v-container>
                    <v-row>
                        <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
                            <v-text-field v-model="activeSubscriber.name" label="Name" required></v-text-field>
                        </v-col>
                        <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
                            <v-text-field v-model="activeSubscriber.email" label="Email" required></v-text-field>
                        </v-col>
                        <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
                            <v-select
                                v-model="activeSubscriber.state"
                                :items="['active', 'unsubscribed', 'junk', 'bounced', 'unconfirmed']"
                                label="State*"
                                required>
                            </v-select>
                        </v-col>
                    </v-row>
                </v-container>
            </v-card-text>
            <v-card-actions>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-btn color="blue-darken-1" variant="text">
                    Close
                </v-btn>
                <v-btn color="blue-darken-1" variant="text" @click="createSubscriber(activeSubscriber)">
                    Save
                </v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
</template>
<script>

import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
    name: 'SubscriberForm',
    props: {
        id: null,
        dialogOpen: false,
    },
    methods: {
        createSubscriber(subscriber) {
            this.$store.dispatch('subscribers/createSubscriber', subscriber).then(() => this.dialogOpen = false).then(() => alert(1));
        }
    },
    watch: {
        id: function(newId) {
            if (newId !== null) {
                this.$store.dispatch('subscribers/getSubscriber', newId);
            }
        },
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters('subscribers', ['activeSubscriber']),
    }
}
</script>
```

Basically, the only thing that I changed compared to examples on their website was switch `v-model` to `:Value` because we are actually passing the properties to the component.

The component is called like that

```
<SubscriberForm :id="subscriberId" :dialog-open="dialogOpen"/>
....
methods: {
    openEditModal(id) {
       this.subscriberId = id;
       this.dialogOpen = true;
   },
},
```

I tried watching the property `dialogOpen` and it gets passed perfectly fine.

What could be the issue?

**UPDATE**: tried the top voted solution at [vuetify: programmatically showing dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446559/vuetify-programmatically-showing-dialog?rq=1)
It resolved the issue, however broke the activator button. So that does not fly as well

Comment: Hey, first thing, if you have an activator in the dialog component, then why pass props from another component to open/close the dialog? Can't you manage dialog toggling from that activator button?

Comment: Second thing, you are passing prop by name `dialog-open` but in the component, you are using it as `dialogOpen`.

Comment: You are joking, right? :)

Comment: Hey, I may not get the question properly, but the help was no joke. Besides, I asked only, not claimed anything.

Comment: Well, thanks for the help, but there is nothing wrong with using different cases (as I mentioned above, the value gets passed to the component itself). Secondly, I need to have buttons both in the component (add button) and in the parent component (table with edit buttons)